# How to create a JList which holds Parameters?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

Hi i'm trying to make a `JList` but it takes 2 Parameters. The list is a list of servers.

```
public class MainMenu extends JPanel {

    Kingdomcraft kd;
    Screen screen;
    JButton playSP;
    JButton playMP;
    JButton settings;
    JButton quit;
    JButton createWorld;
    JButton addServer;
    JSlider sound;
    JSlider light;
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    JList worldList;
    JList serverList;

    private Preferences prefs;
    private int soundLevel;
    private int lightLevel;

    public void run() {

        kd = new Kingdomcraft();
        screen = new Screen();
        playSP = new JButton("Singleplayer");
        playMP = new JButton("Multiplayer");
        settings = new JButton("Settings");
        quit = new JButton("Quit");
        createWorld = new JButton("Create World");
        addServer = new JButton("Add Server");
        sound = new JSlider();
        light = new JSlider();
        prefs  = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(MainMenu.class);
        soundLevel = prefs.getInt("SOUND_LEVEL", 50);
        lightLevel = prefs.getInt("LIGHT_LEVEL", 50);
        worldList = new JList();
        serverList = new JList();

        this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        this.setLayout(null);

        if (kd.inMainMenu) {

            add(createWorld);

            createWorld.setBounds(170, 10, 150, 35);

            add(playSP);

            playSP.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 35);

            playSP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    remove(sound);
                    remove(light);
                    remove(addServer);
                    repaint();
                    add(createWorld);

                    createWorld.setBounds(170, 10, 150, 35);
                }
            });

            add(playMP);

            playMP.setBounds(10, 60, 150, 35);

            playMP.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    remove(sound);
                    remove(light);
                    remove(createWorld);
                    repaint();

                    add(addServer);

                    addServer.setBounds(170, 60, 150, 35);
                }
            });

            add(settings);

            settings.setBounds(10, 110, 150, 35);

            settings.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    remove(createWorld);
                    remove(addServer);
                    repaint();
                    add(sound);

                    sound.setBounds(170, 110, 150, 35);
                    sound.setMinimum(0);
                    sound.setMaximum(100);
                    sound.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
                    sound.setValue(soundLevel);
                    sound.setToolTipText("Audio: " + soundLevel + "%");
                    sound.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                            soundLevel = sound.getValue();

                            sound.setToolTipText("Audio: " + soundLevel + "%");

                            prefs.putInt("SOUND_LEVEL", soundLevel);
                        }
                    });

                    add(light);

                    light.setBounds(330, 110, 150, 35);
                    light.setMinimum(0);
                    light.setMaximum(100);
                    light.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
                    light.setValue(lightLevel);
                    light.setToolTipText("Brightness: " + lightLevel + "%");
                    light.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

                            lightLevel = light.getValue();

                            light.setToolTipText("Brightness: " + lightLevel + "%");

                            prefs.putInt("LIGHT_LEVEL", lightLevel);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            add(quit);

            quit.setBounds(10, 160, 150, 35);

            quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    System.exit(ABORT);
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

The world list appears when you click the Multiplayer `JButton`.
Also when you click the Multiplayer `JButton` a `JButton` appears named Add Server.
Effectively when you add a new server that server would appear on the newly created JList.

How would I do this?

edit: By the way the 2 parameters are Strings serverName, and ServerIP.

Answer (score 2):

### You Could...

Create a key/value property object which holds the two distinct values.  You would then pass this to the `JList` as a single Object.

You would need to supply a custom cell renderer in order to render the value appropriately.

See [How to use lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [Writing a Custom Cell Renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for more details

### You Could...

Use a `JTable`.  While this would allow you to supply each value (key/value) as a separate column, I would still wrap the two in a key/value object, as it would make the management of these values simpler.

This would allow you to interact with each side individually should you wish.

See [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

### You Should...

Make use of appropriate layout managers.  Pixel perfect layouts (`this.setLayout(null);`) are an illusion in modern GUIs.  There are so many aspects of the rendering pipeline you simply don't have control over, which would quickly turn your "pretty" layout on your system into alphabet soup on different systems

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

Comment: ok thx so much i was afraid i made another incorrect question

Comment: of those 3 which do you think looks the best? by this i mean i want there to be some transparency to it so that when i run the game you can still see the background. if you are confused by what this means run my program www.github.com/FeatheredOrcian/Kingdomcraft

Comment: Personally, I would take option 2.  Option 3 isn't optional.  You should be doing that...You should beware that `JTable` is third most complex component in the Swing library...

Comment: ok because my background is like the minecraft main menu where it is animated and i dont want it covered

Comment: Transparency is achievable, but it will take a little work, as you need to make sure that each container you add is made transparent by using `setOpaque(false)`, but some containers, like `JScrollPane` have built in child containers you also need to make transparent...

Comment: if it isnt a bother could you name them off because i think i know them all and then bam i find out that there is a JLabel

Comment: ok im ok with a little work in fact its the work that makes me a better pre-grammer :)

Comment: Take a look at [Using Swing Components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), it pretty much lists all the available components

Comment: ok and dont misunderstand my lack of understanding for being an adolescent programer

Comment: oooh JDialog, wow i couldn't remember  these all if i was paid to

Comment: You get use to it ;) - It's about going "Oh, I want that feature, we did I see it again..."

Comment: Keep that reference close at hand, it will save your life

Comment: So do you specialize in Swing? sorry if i drag a conversation i dont know any programers

Comment: Yep, 15 years and loving it

Comment: Theres times when i think i basicaly understand all of java then i find out theres a whole section like swing that ive never heard of. when im older im going to make an os using primarily java although others have done this]

Comment: Java's huge, seriously, huge, we all the libraries and functionality (like J2EE), you'll never know it all, the best you can hope for is an understanding of how the designers put certain libraries together...:P

Comment: true i could never hope to know a whole language. it astounds me how in som circumstances doing 18 *3 is way faster than doing 3 * 9 * 2